# Shift-Alt Not Working when selecting a face, edge, or vertice loop in Blender 3.3

Tags: vertices, faces, edges, selection-tools

I recently downloaded Blender 3.3. I am having difficulty in selecting a loop of faces, edges, or vertices on an object. In previous versions of Blender, I was able to accomplish this task by selecting a face, holding Shift-Alt and an adjacent face in the direction of the loop of faces I am wanting to select, and then those faces would be highlighted. I am unable to do this using Shift-Alt in Blender 3.3. I found somewhere on the web that if you double tap on the adjacent face,you can select a loop of faces that way. Well, this works to an extent, but most of the time this method ends up selecting the wrong loop.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue and is there a solution? Perhaps a preferrence that I need to select or unselect? Any and all suggestion regarding this matter are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unless you're selecting multiple loops I've never needed to use the Shift key with Alt to select a loop. For a face loop, just go into Face mode and Alt-click on an edge between two of the faces on the loop. Similarly for loops of edges or verts just Alt-click on one of the edges on the loop that you want selected. If you want to add a loop to others already selected, hold down the Shift key and then Alt-click to add a loop as above.

Comment: John Eason, thanks. I will give that a try.